# How to export data from one function to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to have data generated from one function, and have it be used in another function.

So far I have tried:
1. return the object
2. pushing the object into an array
3. iterate through object and push to array
4. load a variable into the function definition.

***Function A: To read the files in a directory***

```
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, '../views/mtemp');

function list(param){
  fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        param.push(file); 
    });
  });
  console.log(param);
}
```

***Function B:Express-Router***

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var param = [];
  list(param);
  console.log(param);
  res.render('task');
});
```

Function A: parse through directory an list the files in it.
Function B: Express-router

I'd like to display the directory without nesting the Func. A into Func. B

Comment: Route middleware are used exactly for this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a promise out of the function, then export and import it

file foo.js

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const {readdir} = require('fs');
const readAsync = promisify(readdir);

module.exports = (path) => readAsync(path);
```

file bar.js

```
const reader = require('./foo');

reader('./').then(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Or in your file

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    const list = await reader('./');
    console.log(list);
    res.render('task');
});
```

---

Don't use fs.readdirSync as proposed in another answer.

Comment: Thanks this worked. But I don't understand any of this. could you explain the solution as well or recommend some good reads to understand the same

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir` is asynchronous.

You could either wrap it in a Promise, or use `fs.readdirSync`

```
function list(){
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
          return rej(err)
      }
      return res(files)
    });
  });
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  list().then( res => {
    console.log(res);
    res.render('task');
  })
});
```